# Is O3 a fixed optimization sequence? And how to change frame-pointer value in LLVM IR?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm

I use the following command to figure out the sequence of clang O3,

`$ opt -enable-new-pm=0 -O3 -debug-pass=Arguments input.ll`

and I get a very long optimization sequence.

Is that sequence same for all of code? Or O3 can change the order according to the source code?

And, I found that if I use `-O0` flag to generate IR file, the attributes may be like this,

```
attributes #0 = { noinline nounwind uwtable "frame-pointer"="all" "min-legal-vector-width"="0" "no-trapping-math"="true" "stack-pr    otector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+cx8,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "tune-cpu"="generic" }
attributes #1 = { "frame-pointer"="all" "no-trapping-math"="true" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-    features"="+cx8,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "tune-cpu"="generic" }
```

we can see the value of `frame-pointer = all`, and I think that may let the code slow.
( It will be turned to `none` by using O3 flag)

How can I change this value by `opt` command?

thanks a lot.

Comment: if any answer helps you, please click the green check mark to make it [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, optimization sequence is the same for all inputs. But note that `opt`'s -O3 may not be the same as `clang`'s -O3.

As for disabling the frame pointer, you can remove it

- with `-fomit-frame-pointer` when generating LLVM IR with `clang`:

```
$ clang input.c -emit-llvm -S -O0 -o fp.ll
$ grep frame-pointer fp.ll
attributes #0 = { ... "frame-pointer"="all" ... }
$ clang input.c -emit-llvm -S -O0 -fomit-frame-pointer -o nofp.ll
$ grep frame-pointer nofp.ll
attributes #0 = { ... "frame-pointer"="none" ... }
```

- with `-frame-pointer=none` when optimizing LLVM IR with `opt`

```
$ opt -frame-pointer=none fp.ll -S -o fp_removed.ll
$ grep frame-pointer fp_removed.ll
attributes #0 = { ... "frame-pointer"="none" ... }
```

Comment: Thank you!!
But I have used the flag `-frame-pointer=none` on opt command but nothing changed.
The whole command I use,
`$ opt -S -enable-new-pm=0 -frame-pointer=none input.ll -o output.ll`

Comment: I just used the command below:

`clang -fomit-frame-pointer -emit-llvm -S input.ll -o output.ll`

But still nothing changed.

Comment: clang the `C file` not `llvm IR` is fine to change `frame-pointer` to `none`. Thanks!
But also cannot change the value by IR.

Comment: @Shane I've updated my answer with examples. You are right, optimizing already generated LLVM IR with `clang` does not seem to work (only `opt` works in this case).